# getWritableDatabase function causing an error

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am creating an application named Mycontacts. Which is the same as a video on youtube(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=38DOncHIazs).

But this `getWritableDatabase()` is causing an error

> Non-static method 'getWritableDatabase()' cannot be referenced from a static context

```
public class addcontacts extends AppCompactActivity
{ 

    EditText conname, conmobno, conemail;
    Context context = this;
    userDbHelper userdbhelp;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addcontacts);
        conname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name);
        conmobno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Contno);
        conemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Eid);
    }

    public void addContest(View view)  {
        String name = conname.getText().toString();
        String mobno = conmobno.getText().toString();
        String conem = conemail.getText().toString();
        userdbhelp = new userDbHelper(context);
        sqLiteDatabase = userDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        userdbhelp.addinformation(name,mobno,conem, sqLiteDatabase);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"data saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        userdbhelp.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
userdbhelp = new userDbHelper(context);
sqLiteDatabase = userDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

to

```
userdbhelp = new userDbHelper(context);
sqLiteDatabase = userdbhelp.getWritableDatabase();
```

You need to invoke the method on the instance `userdbhelp`, not on the class `userDbHelper`.